# Capturing an incoming call number

Tags: java, android, android-studio

### UPDATE 1:

I found the problem! When installing the APP, the user is **not being asked for permission**. I did it manually and it worked. **New question**, how do I get the app to request permission at startup?

### ORIGINAL TEXT

I am trying to capture the incoming call number, but to no avail!

No error appears, that's the problem, so I must be missing some detail!

Here on stackoverflow, there are a lot of topics, but all are very old, and the answers don't work ...

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="net.aaa.androidcall">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

### ServiceReceiver.java

```
package net.aaaa.androidcall;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String Number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Number: " +Number+ ", Status: "+ state,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT,3,0);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing that is not displaying the number in the toast?

Comment: Are you sure you have all the required permissions to get `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER

Comment: @O95 The required permissions are not the ones I stated in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @O95 I found the problem! When installing the APP, the user is not being asked for permission. I did it manually and it worked. New question, how do I get the app to request permission at startup?

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting with this problem for a week and after I read your entry, I solved the problem, Thank you very much.
It is adding this line to main activity:

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 1);`